# How to Change the statistics action name when using implicit tracking

Tags: outbound-email

I am using implicit tracking. But when I use internal component in newsletter. Then I am able to track the link click. But in the statistics tab I want full url of that component instead of TCM id. Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the 'title' of the link by also setting a tridion:title attribute (in addition to the tridion:href attribute you have already provided).

You can specify anything in there, but be aware that Contacts will see this title when their mouse is over the link. So it's best to have it be a meaningful description of what the link point to.

Comment: Peter, Is this possible to get URL of that component?

Comment: If you mean resolving the Component link to a URL on the website, no -- I don't see an easy way to do that which also guarantees that the URL is still valid. I recommend using a few words to describe the link instead, intended for your Contacts to understand -- and your users will still have an easy time identifying the link in the statistics too.

Comment: Peter, When I added a title field in the link. Implicit tracking stops working. It works if I remove title from the anchor link.

Comment: Did you make it invalid XHTML with your change? Perhaps the prefix hasn't be declared correctly?